# Group by week by using Linq2DB for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, linq, linq2db

I am using Linq2DB for PostgreSQL. I need to group the data by week in Linq. Below is my code:

```
Func<DateTime,int> weekProjector = d => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(d,
                                                         CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,
                                                         DayOfWeek.Sunday);

var ddquery = from t in db.VLogData
              group t by weekProjector(t.NewTime);

foreach (var f in ddquery)
{
    f.Key.ToString();
}
```

But it show the error or foreach there

> (xxx.Controllers.DashboardController+<>c__DisplayClass1_0).weekProjector,
>   selectParam.NewTime)' cannot be converted to SQL.'

May I know what is the issue there?

Comment: "cannot be converted to SQL." Isn't that clear? What should `weekProjector(t.NewTime)` look like in SQL?

Comment: When I answer such questions, I request expected SQL. If it is doable via SQL, then it is not a problem to explain for linq2db how to generate appropriate SQL.

Answer (score 2):

`weekProjector` is a client-side function, but you pass server-side data to it as input. To make it work you can:

- perform grouping on client by pasting `AsEnumerable()` call between Select and `GroupBy` calls (worst option ever)
- tell linq2db which aggregation logic to use by applying `Sql.ExpressionAttribute` or `Sql.ExtensionAttribute` on `weekProjector` with SQL expression and `IsAggregate=true` set for attribute
- same as previous, but by using `ExpressionMethodAttribute` to define aggregation logic using C# expressions